# update html table with data from SQL database table in cshtml page

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@{ 
     var db = Database.Open("HEMS");
     var LoadDevCmd = "SELECT * FROM " + App.UserMeterID;
     var DevQuery = db.Query(LoadDevCmd);

     foreach (var row in DevQuery)
     {
        var DevType = row.DeviceType;
        var LoadType = row.Device_LoadType;
        string Loc = row.Location;
        var MAC = row.MACaddress;
        var D_Status = row.DeviceStatus;

        var myLoc = "";

        if (Loc == null)
        {

           myLoc = "XLoc";
        } 
        else
        {
            switch (Loc)
            {
                case "Living Room":
                   myLoc = "LivingRoom";

                break;

                case "Bedroom":
                   myLoc = "Bedroom";
                break;

                case "Bathroom":
                   myLoc = "Bathroom";
                break;

                case "Dining Room":
                   myLoc = "DiningRoom";
                break;

                case "Kitchen":
                   myLoc = "Kitchen";
                break;

                case "Balcony":
                   myLoc = "Balcony";
                break;

                case "Others":
                    myLoc = "Others";
                break;
           }

     }
}



<body>
    <table id="XLoc">
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Unknown Location</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="LivingRoom">
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Living Room</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="Bedroom">
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Bedroom</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="Bathroom">
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Bathroom</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="DiningRoom">
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Dining Room</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="Kitchen">
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Kitchen</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="Balcony">
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Balcony</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="Others">
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Others</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

<script>

    function displayDev(id, MAC) {
        var table = document.getElementById(id);
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = "MacAddress: " + MAC ;

    }

</script>
```

I'm trying update my html tables in  tag as shown above with the script function( displayDev(id, MAC)}. May I know how may I call the script function in the @{}?

I've tried the page.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(); but I always get null page which cause the NullReferenceException error, may I know how should I fix it?

Comment: You can't call it in your @{}.  That script is client-side.  The @{} code is server-side.  The best you can do is create a script that auto-calls `displayDev` on page load.  Though I'm not sure why you'd do that instead of loading it server-size with razor.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, may I know how can I "load it  server-size with razor?"

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, may I know how can I "load it  server-size with razor?"

or, do you have any ideas of passing server-side variable to client-side? I tried to use the script tag to call the function in @{} and it works, but I couldn't find a way to pass the variable from @{} to the script function~ any ideas? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `@Html.Raw("displayDev(" + myLoc + ")")`